# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not linking library

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ld

I'm trying to compile a program and during the configure checks one library cannot be found. Linking in my .bashrc file to this library with:

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/:/users/much/needed/library/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/other/libs/

 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

after that I source the .bashrc file with

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

and check with echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to see if the LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the path to the library I need (and it's there).

However, when I run ./configure again - the same error appears. Do you have any hints as to what might be wrong here? I can't find any problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you try exporting `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/:/users/much/needed/library/"` in addition to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` you mentioned?
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` tells the loader where to find libraries when executing a binary at runtime, but the linker needs to find the required library at link time too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to run ldconfig to create the linker bindings.  Add the directory to /etc/ld.so.conf and then run ldconfig (as root).

Comment: I don't have root privileges on this system.

Comment: You could also try this:
export LDFLAGS=' -L/path/to/your/library'

and if you also need to supply headers
export CPPFLAGS=' -I/path/to/lib/include'